# HighCharts: Color of label according to the color of pie slice

Tags: colors, label, highcharts

Title of this questions says everything. I only found out how to change the color of connectors. If I delete the `color:` option, they´re all grey. I tried to put in the field with stored colors in hex, with no result, stayed black.

Comment: I tried what I typed above in my question. I know that color is changed via "color", but it seems it only works when I type static hex value...and I don´t want all labels to have the same color.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In `dataLabels.formatter` you have access to `this.point.color`. So simple set `useHTML: true` for dataLabels, and create spans with specified colors.

Comment: could you please explain with a jsfiddle for pie chart i tried and am failing please help urgent . this is my effort http://jsfiddle.net/a6hW6/

Comment: Formatter for `dataLabels`, not for `dataLabels.color`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/a6hW6/1/

Answer (score 0):

the formatter function gives you a callback object, which has a color property that can be set with the color of your choice

```
formatter: (format) ->
  format.color = @point.color
```

Comment: @LeaCohen don't know for sure, but generally the formatter is applied within the plotOptions.  That is `{ ... plotOptions: { <chart type;bar,line,etc> : { formatter: <function> } } }`