# Highcharts change label text for a single series

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

In my stacked bar highchart you will see that I have set my last series to the color grey. Is there any way to set the text color to black where the series background color is grey?

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'percent',
    },
    bar: {
        stacking: 'percent',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{y}%',
            style: {
                color: '#ffffff' //This is where i set the color to white
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jimbob25/V446C/

Comment: possible duplicate of [HighCharts: Color of label according to the color of pie slice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872718/highcharts-color-of-label-according-to-the-color-of-pie-slice)

Comment: I tried doing the same thing as that example, it didnt work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set color for each series separately, see: http://jsfiddle.net/V446C/5/

```
series: [{
    name: 'Poor',
    color: '#E9E9E9',
    data: [12, 23, 13, 18, 7, 19, 9],
    dataLabels: {
        style: {
            color: '#000000'
        }
    }
}, {
    name: 'Satisfactory',
    color: '#629AC0',
    data: [42, 45, 35, 57, 29, 61, 26]
}, {
    name: 'Excellent',
    color: '#006FBC',
    data: [46, 32, 52, 25, 64, 20, 65]
}]
```

Comment: thank you, Do you know how i can remove the axis line all the way to the left as well?